# Visual studio 2013 immediate window and searching slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, immediate-window

I'm running visual studio 2013 with resharper.  Fast machine, 24gb of memory, editing, compiling is all lightning fast.

If I try to search within the file, or I try to type a command into the immediate window, it's  unusable slow - like literally 40 seconds between key strokes.

Any idea what's going on, and how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any other extensions installed? Also do you have any remote URLs configured for DLL sources?

Comment: other extensions = spec flow.   Don't think I have any remote urls, but will check

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Did you ever find out what was happening?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, with Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8. So I updated to Resharper 9 and… *voila*! The problem was fixed! I believe it is a bug in Resharper 8.

Comment: Sadly, not for me it doesn't

Comment: On latest version of Resharper and command window is still unbearably slow.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Googled on it - nothing helped. Somehow I was in need to close VS2013. After opening VS2013 issue was fixed. So try to reboot VS2013.